# How to connect Bluetooth to COM port

Tags: windows, bluetooth, serial-port, port

Anyone know how to add COM port to my Bluetooth devices in my laptop?
I'm using windows 8.1
In device manager I can't see any of COM ports.
I need to connect my Bluetooth with COM port because I need to send data through it.

Thanks for help.